# EMR cluster In-transit encryption is failing with "Invalid S3Provider"

Tags: security, amazon-s3, encryption, terraform, amazon-emr

I am creating EMR cluster 6.9.0 with Spark application via Terraform. If I disable In-Transit encryption, then my cluster is working fine and jobs are running successfully. Now, when I enable this encryption and provide .pem files in S3 location and provide the s3 path in the terraform configuration, my EMR cluster creation fails.

Terraform configuration:

```
{
  "EncryptionConfiguration": {
        "EnableInTransitEncryption": true,
        "EnableAtRestEncryption": true,
        "InTransitEncryptionConfiguration": {
            "TLSCertificateConfiguration": {
                "CertificateProviderType": "PEM",
                "S3Object": "arn:aws:s3:::sample-mybucket/certs/MyCerts.zip"
            }
        },
       "AtRestEncryptionConfiguration": {
            "LocalDiskEncryptionConfiguration": {
                "EnableEbsEncryption": true,
                "EncryptionKeyProviderType": "AwsKms",
                "AwsKmsKey": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:dummy:key/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012"
            }
       }
    }
}
```

It throws the below error.

```
On the master instance (i-123456789), Invalid S3Provider: Failed to read the private key from /tmp/emr-encryption/privateKey.pem
```

I am not getting much information about the error. On the IAM role which run the terraform job as well as S3 bucket has permissions for each other.

IAM role permissions:

```
{
  "Sid": "S3AllowReads",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
     "s3:Get*",
     "s3:List*"
  ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*mybucket*"
}
```

I haven't specified this /tmp/emr-encryption path, I am assuming IAM role which is creating EMR cluster would download the file to this location. If the assumption is correct, then please clarify, is this the local path or hdfs path.

My S3 bucket has server-side encryption enabled with the same AWS KMS key which is provided in the LocalDiskEncryptionConfiguration and IAM role which is creating the cluster from Terraform has access to this KMS key.

I can also see in CloudTrail, that there are many errors against the following events

1. GetBucketReplication -> ReplicationConfigurationNotFoundError
2. GetBucketLifecycle -> NoSuchLifecycleConfiguration
3. GetBucketCors -> NoSuchCORSConfiguration
4. GetBucketObjectLockConfiguration -> ObjectLockConfigurationNotFoundError
5. GetBucketWebsite -> NoSuchWebsiteConfiguration

If there is any more information that is required to fix this issue, please let me know. Am I missing some configuration in any of the xml configuration files (core-site, yarn-site etc) or the issue is somewhere else?

}

Answer (score 0):

EMR is trying to install your certs and unable to access your  private key provided on MyCerts.zip file. During installation, EMR will download this privateKey.pem to local disk of EMR nodes. check if your privateKey.pem is readable with openssl tool. is it encrypted using passphrase ?

```
openssl pkey -in privateKey.pem -pubout -outform pem
```

recheck how the certs are created and validate if they are in correct format
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-encryption-enable.html#emr-encryption-certificates